# Does a forward_iterator template class make sense?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, std

The C++ standard library contains the convenient template class `std::move_iterator`. Given the close relationship between `std::move` and `std::forward`, why is there no equivalent `std::forward_iterator`? Example usage:

```
template <typename C>
auto foo(C&& values)
{
    remove_reference_t<C> result {};
    result.reserve(values.size());
    std::transform(std::make_forward_iterator<C>(std::begin(values)),
                   std::make_forward_iterator<C>(std::end(values))), 
                   std::back_inserter(result), Bar());
    return result;
}
```

The idea being I can now use `foo` like:

```
std::vector<ComplexType> values {/* lots of values */};

auto copied_fooed = foo(values); 
// or
auto moved_fooed  = foo(std::move(values));
```

Without having to write two `foo`s.

Comment: Proper name would be `std::forwardable_iterator` to avoid clashes with classical Forward Iterator.

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks. Fixed (I think).

Comment: Are you asking why there isn't one (make a proposal?) or how to write one?

Comment: @Barry Both; the two aren't mutually exclusive. Either there is no good reason to have one, it isn't possible to have one, or it's an oversight. I'd like to know which (and why), of course if it's the latter I'd consider a proposal. A valid implementation would certainly help answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer *why* such a thing doesn't exist. But it's certainly implementable. Basically, your `C` type is either an lvalue reference (in which case just pass through the argument) or it's not a reference (in which case, use [`std::make_move_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_move_iterator)).

First, let's start with a great addition to any toolkit, [almost static if](https://rmf.io/cxx11/almost-static-if/) (with minor changes):

```
namespace detail {
    enum class enabler {};
}

template <bool B>
using EnableIf = std::enable_if_t<B, detail::enabler>;
```

And now we just use SFINAE on the two overloads:

```
template <typename C,
          typename Iterator,
          EnableIf<std::is_lvalue_reference<C>::value>...>
Iterator make_forward_iterator(Iterator i)
{
    return i;
}

template <typename C,
          typename Iterator,
          EnableIf<!std::is_lvalue_reference<C>::value>...>
auto make_forward_iterator(Iterator i)
{
    return std::make_move_iterator(i);
}
```

---

Alternatively, and this is probably simpler, could just tag-dispatch:

```
namespace detail {    
    template <typename Iterator>
    Iterator make_forward_iterator(Iterator i, std::true_type )
    {
        return i;
    }

    template <typename Iterator>
    auto make_forward_iterator(Iterator i, std::false_type )
    {
        return std::make_move_iterator(i);
    }
}

template <typename C, typename Iterator>
auto make_forward_iterator(Iterator i) {
    return detail::make_forward_iterator(i, std::is_lvalue_reference<C>{});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit more complex than that.

With an owning container, the l/r valueness of the container imply move iterators may be of use.

But for views, this does not work: moving from an rvalue view is destructive of unowned state.

Practically, this means the decision to move or not based on l/r valueness is matter for both the context and value to mutually decide, which makes it tricky.

Range-v3 and concepts may make this easier to reason about.