# Forwarding the same value to two or more functions

Tags: c++, c++11, forwarding-reference

When using forwarding references, is it a bad idea to forward the
same value to more than one function? Consider the following piece of code:

```
template<typename Container>
constexpr auto
front(Container&& c)
-> typename Container::value_type
{ return std::forward<Container>(c).front(); }

template<typename Container>
constexpr auto
back(Container&& c)
-> typename Container::value_type
{ return std::forward<Container>(c).back(); }

template<typename Container>
constexpr auto
get_corner(Container&& c)
{
    return do_something(front(std::forward<Container(c)),
                        back(std::forward<Container>(c));
}
```

If `Container` is an lvalue-reference, the function works just fine. However, I'm worrying about situations where rvalues are passed on to it, because the value would get invalidated once a move occurs. My doubt is: Is there a correct way to forward the container in that case, without losing the value category?

Comment: "is it a bad idea to forward the same value to more than one function? Consider the following piece of code:" In general, yes. In some specific use cases, it's harmless.It can only hurt you, really. In your specific use case, why forward at all?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In general, it is not reasonable for the same function to forward the same parameter twice. Not unless it has specific knowledge of what the receiver of that forwarded parameter will do.

Remember: the behavior of `std::forward` can be equivalent to the behavior of `std::move`, depending on what parameter the user passed in. And the behavior of an xvalue will be contingent on how the receiving function processes it. If the receiver takes a non-const rvalue reference, it will likely *move* from that value if possible. That would leave you holding a moved-from object. If it takes a value, it will *certainly* move from it if the type supports it.

So unless you have *specific knowledge* of the expected behavior of the operations you are using, it is not safe to forward a parameter more than once.

Comment: So the right thing to do here is to only accept a const lvalue-reference to a container?

Comment: @thist: Here, because neither `front()` nor `back()` should ever perform a move, passing a const lvalue reference to them is correct.  In general, the right approach is `func1(rvaluerefparam); func2(rvaluerefparam); func3(std::forward(rvaluerefparam));`  That is, let only the last user steal the resources.

Comment: @thlst: `forward` is only ever useful to seamlessly pass both references and r-value references; if you simply limit the issue to non r-value references (to prevent moves), then you can pass the same reference (const or not) to multiple functions. If mutable, the order in which functions are called matter.

Answer (score 4):

There's actually no rvalue-reference version of `std::begin` - we just have (setting aside `constexpr` and return values):

```
template <class C>
??? begin(C& );

template <class C>
??? begin(C const& );
```

For lvalue containers, you get `iterator`, and for rvalue containers, you get `const_iterator` (or whatever the container-specific equivalent ends up being).

The one real problem in your code is returning `decltype(auto)`. For lvalue containers, that's fine - you'll return a reference to an object whose lifetime exceeds the function. But for rvalue containers, that's returning a dangling reference. You'll want to return a *reference* for lvalue containers and a *value* for rvalue containers.

On top of that, `forward`-ing the containers into `begin()`/`end()` is probably not what you want to do. It'd be more efficient to conditionally wrap the result of the `select()` as a move iterator. Something like [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33125670/2069064):

```
template <typename Container,
          typename V = decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<Container&>())),
          typename R = std::conditional_t<
              std::is_lvalue_reference<Container>::value,
              V,
              std::remove_reference_t<V>
              >
          >
constexpr R operator()(Container&& c)
{
    auto it = select(std::begin(c), std::end(c));
    return *make_forward_iterator<Container>(it);
}
```

There's probably a less verbose way to express all of that.

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't show how to forward the same value to more functions.

Comment: @thlst Okay but your question was about the piece of code you posted. If you want to ask a question about a different piece of code, post a different piece of code?

Comment: @Barry: His question was quite clear; the code was just *an example*, one possible piece of code. He's not asking a "will this code work" question. He's asking "is it possible to do this, with an example".

Answer (score 3):

You presumably realize that you wouldn't want to `std::move` an object being passed to multiple functions:

```
std::string s = "hello";
std::string hello1 = std::move(s);
std::string hello2 = std::move(s);  // hello2 != "hello"
```

The role of `forward` is simply to restore any rvalue status that a parameter had when it was passed to the function.

We can quickly demonstrate that it is bad practice by `forward`ing one parameter two times to a function that has a move effect:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct S {
    std::string name_ = "defaulted";
    S() = default;
    S(const char* name) : name_(name) {}
    S(S&& rhs) { std::swap(name_, rhs.name_); name_ += " moved"; }
};

void fn(S s)
{
    std::cout << "fn(" << s.name_ << ")\n";
}

template<typename T>
void fwd_test(T&& t)
{
    fn(std::forward<T>(t));
    fn(std::forward<T>(t));
}

int main() {
    fwd_test(S("source"));
}
```

http://ideone.com/NRM8Ph

If forwarding was safe, we should see `fn(source moved)` twice, but instead we see:

```
fn(source moved)
fn(defaulted moved)
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, yes, this is potentially dangerous.

Forwarding a parameter ensures that if the value received by the universal reference parameter is an rvalue of some sort, it will continue to be an rvalue when it is forwarded. If the value is ultimately forwarded to a function (such as a move-constructor) that *consumes* the value by moving from it, its internal state is not likely to be valid for use in subsequent calls.

If you do not forward the parameter, it will not (in general) be eligible for move operations, so you would be safe from such behavior.

In your case, `front` and `back` (both the free functions and the member functions) do not perform a move on the container, so the specific example you gave should be safe. However, this also demonstrates that there's no reason to forward the container, since an rvalue won't be given different treatment from an lvalue--which is the only reason to preserve the distinction by forwarding the value in the first place.