How to use the captured arguments to a constructor, and use those arguments subsequently in another constructor?
Consider a class Base which has many constructors each with different types. The only common thing is the penultimate parameter of each constructor. I take a copy of this parameter on the way in using a function get_penultimate and assign it to m_foo the details of which are not relevant here.
I've written a class Child:
template<class Base>
class Child : public Base
{
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    Child(Args&&... args) :
        Base(std::forward<Args>(args)...),
        m_foo(get_penultimate(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    {
        // Store the arguments in m_args
        (this->m_args.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
    }

    std::vector<std::any> m_args;
    FooType m_foo;
};

What I want to be able to do is to create a new instance of Base using m_args. (In reality, I'm changing the penultimate argument of m_args by changing m_foo and adjusting the std::vector). But m_args cannot be forwarded perfectly.
The idea would be to have a function in Child:
template <typename... Args>
Base createBase() const
{
    return Base(std::forward<Args>(m_args)); // Not allowed
}

How can I do this? I'm using C++17.

rather than Base(std::forward<Args>(args)...), you want Base(m_args) ?

or rather Base(std::forward_all_but_one<Args>(args...)) ?

its not clear what exactly you mean with  "create a new instance of Base". An instance not yet shown in the code? Or the base subobject of Child ?

Please provide failing test (not compiling is also falling test). Aim is to provide couple examples of usage. Or maybe API design is wrong.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I've added the function.

I would consider designing API in different way, for example: Child(std::tuple<Ts...> t, FooType foo) : Base(std::move(t)), m_foo(std::move(foo)). In such case using will be also more readable.

where would you call that function ? In the constructor? Once you moved from args you cannot move again, so why is it important to forward twice?

It's a way of creating a copy of the object but with one of the parameters changed.

ok, copy, one param less, thats clear, but all the rest I dont understand. Suppose Base(std::forward<Args>(args)...) moves all args then m_foo(get_penultimate(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) potentially moves again, and you want to forward once more. Why? See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/39322118/4117728

@463035818_is_not_an_ai: At the level of the child I'm only interested in the penultimate parameter. That's the one I want to play with in the child class.

please show a compelte example

std::vector::size is a runtime information, and you also lose type information. You might store a factory instead (std::function<Base()>).

This seems overly complicated. Why not template<typename... Args, typename Foo, typename Final> Child(Args&&... args, Foo&& foo, Final&& final) ?

std::vector::size is a runtime information, and you also lose type information. You might store a factory instead (std::function<Base()>):
template<class Base>
class Child : public Base
{
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    Child(Args&&... args) :
        Base(args...), // No forward (move), as used also after
        factory{
            [&]<std::size_t...Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
                return [=](){
                    return Base(std::get<Is>(std::tie(args...))..., 42);
                };
            }(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args) - 1>{})
        }
    {
    }

    std::function<Base()> factory;
};

Demo

Clever (+1), but isn't the behaviour of the code undefined as you've already forwarded args when constructing Base? Base(args...), is a fix?

Depends how Base constructor handles (potentially) moved-from object afterward. Changed to avoid that pitfall.
